# Check if couple of values exists in SQLite database

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

I have a table in my SQLite database which consists of a couple of int and I want to check if couples already exists before adding a new row.

I have this function that returns datas from the table TableName(id1, id2) :

```
public Cursor getIds() {
        return db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME, null);
    }
```

In a other class, I have these :

```
int int1 = 14
int int2 = 2564

if (????) {
        m.addToTable(int1, int2);
} else {
        //Datas already exists
}
```

What I need to do to compare int1 with value from column id1 and int2 with value from column id2 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create this method:

```
public boolean existIds(int id1, int id2) {
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(
            "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE id1 = ? AND id2 = ?",
            new String[]{String.valueOf(id1), String.valueOf(id2)}
    );
    boolean result = c.getCount() > 0;
    c.close();
    return result;
}
```

Now you can use it in your code:

```
int int1 = 14
int int2 = 2564

if (!existIds(int1, int2)) {
    m.addToTable(int1, int2);
} else {
    //do something because the ids already exist
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I need !

Comment: This may suit the OP's use case, but note in general that this approach is not thread safe.

Answer (score 0):

If you plan on ultimately doing an insert into your SQLite table, and you want to prevent that, should there be a record which already contains those two values, then consider this option:

```
INSERT INTO TableName (id1, id2)
SELECT ?, ?
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM TableName WHERE id1 = ? and id2 = ?);
```

To the `?` placeholders you would bind the two values to be inserted.  For the example you gave, you would end up running this query:

```
INSERT INTO TableName (id1, id2)
SELECT 14, 2564
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM TableName WHERE id1 = 14 and id2 = 2564);
```

Comment: Thank you for your help but @forpas' answer suits better for my program

Comment: @VanDiest Keep in kind that the answer you accepted is not thread safe.  If the check passes, it is still possible that another thread may come in and do the same insert, thus resulting in duplicate records.

Comment: Consider using explicitly numbered (or named) parameters so you only have to bind each value once instead of twice: `select ?1, ?2 from ... where id1 = ?1 and id2 = ?2 ...`